# How do i find the max value in a list that contains a list as a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an exercise for a class in python and i have stuck in question 4:

1. Create `list1` with 200 random integers in space [1,50] and print how many times the number is 10.
2. Create `list2` with 50 integers [1,2,3, ..., 50] and then with `append()` function join the lists together and display the size.
3. Delete the data with index number from 99 to 130 and print the list size after deleting items.
4. Find the maximum and minimum in the list.

My first thought on how to find MAX was to sort the list and get the last value but because 1 item in the list is a list I get this error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`.

Any ideas on what i have to do?
My code until this question is the one below:

```
import numpy as np

#Question1
j= 0; 
list1 = list(range(200))  #decalre list1

for i in range(200): 
 list1[i] = np.random.randint(50)     #create a list of length 200 with values 0 to 50.
 if list1[i] == 10: 
   j = j+1

print("Number 10 exists ",j,"times in the list.")

#QUESTION2
list2 = list(range(1,51))  #Declare list2
list1.append(list2)  #append list2 on list1
print(len(list1)) 

#QUESTION3
for i in range(99,130):  # deletes the items with an index number from 99 to 130
   list1.pop(i)

print(len(list1))
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. You probably should use `append` in a loop to append the individual items, not the list as a whole, so the list stays a list of numbers. Also note that if you `pop` in the loop, you actually pop the elements at positions 99, 101, 103, ...

Comment: Also, the way the list is constructed, the `min` and `max` are guaranteed to be 1 and 50 respectively (the values from `lst2`, which are not random and never get removed)

Comment: Okay i will try it.Thank you very much for answering my question. I'm kinda new to python,still trying to get the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten your list first before you can make any comparisons as you can't compare a `list` with an `int`. In order to do this you can create a recursive function and pass your list

```
def flatten(l):
    return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten(x) for x in l), [])
```

Be aware the the `list` in the above code is a protected name by Python and refers to a list data type. What this function does is compare each item in the lists and checks if it is a list type. If not it adds it to the list, if it is it calls the function again and goes to the next item. You can now run the following:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> flatten(list1)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can now run Python's built in `max()` and `min()` functions

```
>>> max(flatten(list1))
>>> 8
>>> min(flatten(list1))
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a built-in function to solve this problem:
`max([2, 5, 4, 9, 3, 7])`
`9`
I would merge the lists, so appending the items of list2 to list1, so you just have only one axis, then you can use the built-in function
If you don't want to merge the list you can first get the maximum of the list inside the list. Then you can take the maximum of this maximum and the other part of your outer list.

Also you can change this line:
`list1[i] = np.random.randint(50)`
You can import random (it's a built-in module) instead and do it this way:
`list1[i] = random.randint(1, 50)`
but probably numpy is faster.
If you want to use numpy you nevertheless need to change the line to:
`list1[i] = np.random.randint(1, 50)`

You need to change your deleting loop in question 3, because if you delete item 99 then the item 100 is the new item 99, so you delete only each second element. You can fix that problem by going backwards from 130 to 99:
`for i in range(130, 99):`

I hope i could help you with this question.

Comment: My list named list1 contains 200 numbers and a list.For example : [1,4,6,...,65,[1,2,3,..,50]].How can i make max() work with an int and a list ?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question exactly. Python will not be able to compare integers with a list: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code added in your code:
 `list2 = list1.pop(-1)
 list3 = list1 + list2
 print(max(list3))
 print(min(list3))`

## Notice there are two lists in list1!